# Maxium number of ordered pairs in an anti-symmetric relation on n symbols.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A= \{ 1,2,3,...,n \} $
If R is a relation on A that is anti symmetric, what is the maximum number of ordered pairs that can be in R and how many relations on A have this maximum size.

Well id like to think about this in terms of Matrices i determined that for row 1 we have n ordered pairs (maximally) then i considered row 2 and the last row i said this yields n pairs as well. i claimed that i had $\frac {n}{2}$ of these rows so i had $\frac {n^2}{2}$ ordered pairs. 
this is clearly wrong just choose n=3 or any other odd number.

Counting the second part is perhaps easier. I claimed that we wanted it had to be symmetric. then i simply said for each remain entry on the upper part of the matrix i want either that entry to be a yes ( for a the relation) or no corresponding to a yes on the lower part of the matrix. i wanted to claim by the same counting logic as above that this yielded $\frac {n(n-1)}{2}$ choices or $2^{(\frac {n}{2})}$ number of ways to reach a maximum size of ordered pairs but this has the same flaw when n is odd as above.

Any ideas how im supposed to count this?

Edit: i found a similiar question that seems to imply that the maximum number of ordered pairs is $\frac {n(n-1)}{2}$ but that seems too few to me it feels like thats not counting the entire diagonal line which is n pairs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are thinking of $R$ as a $n \times n$ matrix where $R_{i,j}=1$ if $(i,j)\in R$ and $R_{i,j}=0$ otherwise.
You can always set the diagonal entries to $1$ without it restricting any of the other entries, thus since we are maximizing the number of 1s we have $R_{i,i}=1$ for all $i$. Now since $R$ is anti-symmetric at most half of the non-diagonal entries are 1s. Thus for each unordered pair $\{i,j\}$ with $i\neq j$ we choose between $R_{i,j}=1$ (implying $R_{j,i}=0$) and $R_{j,i}=1$ (implying $R_{i,j}=0$). Since there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ such unordered pairs, there are $2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ maximal anti-symmetric relations, and they are of size $n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.